# Разделение .h и .cpp файлов по папкам в VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Собственно VS при создании новых файлов в проекте просто сохраняет их в корень проекта. Как можно сохранять их в папку внутри корня? Например назвать папку src и чтобы туда все исходники сохранялись. А также можно ли разделить .h и .cpp файлы по разным папкам?

Comment: Ну просто положите их туда, в чем вопрос? Когда создаете - выберите соответствующую подпапку...

Comment: @Harry я создал папку src в проводнике, перекинул туда файлы. В VS они помечены как просто удаленные. И создать файлы в эту папку я не могу

Comment: Перенесите с помощью VS, само собой. Он же должен знать, что это сделано.

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар показывает, что у в Solution Explorer выбран режим отображения фильтров, а не режим отображения файловой системы.